# Parse data from csv file into given format using Prolog

Tags: csv, prolog, swi-prolog

I have the csv file that contains data as:

```
  A  B  C
A -  4  5
B 8  -  6
C 2  3  -
```

I want to have facts in the following form:

```
num(a,b,4).
num(a,c,5).
num(b,a,8).
num(b,c,6).
num(c,a,2).
num(c,b,3).
```

There should not be facts for similar alphabets like num(a,a,-).

I am using prolog's csv_read_file as:

```
csv_read_file(Path, Rows, [functor(num), arity(4)]), maplist(assert, Rows).
```

and its giving me output as:

```
Rows = [num('', 'A', 'B', 'C'), num('A', -, 4, 5), num('B', 8, -, 6), num('C', 2, 3, -)]
```

It seems to be a basic question, but I am not able to think about condition to perform this. Any help will be highly appreciated.

**As per Isabelle Newbie Answer:**

```
Open :- csv_read_file('Path', Rows, [functor(num), arity(4)]), table_entry(Rows, Row).


header_row_entry(Header,Row,Entry):-
    arg(1, Row, RowName),
    functor(Header, _, Arity),
    between(2,Arity,ArgIndex),
    arg(ArgIndex, Header, ColumnName),
    arg(ArgIndex, Row, Value),
    Entry = num(RowName, ColumnName, Value),
    writeln(Entry).

table_entry(Entries, Entry):-
    Entries = [Header | Rows],
    member(Row, Rows),
    header_row_entry(Header, Row, Entry).
```

Now, can anyone explain how and where I should use maplist to convert the rows in form of facts (neglect filtering of '-' and lowercase for now) so that when I query:

```
?-num(A,B,X).
```

I should get:

```
X=4
```

Next task is, I want to implement depth first search algorithm on it. Any details regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: That is not a CSV file.

Comment: Its obvious, you can assume commas in between @GuyCoder

Answer (score 3):

Consider a table header `num('', 'A', 'B', 'C')` and a row in the table `num('B', 8, -, 6)`. From this you want to compute a table entry identified by the row's name, which here is `'B'`, and by a column name: the column name being `'A'` for the first value (`8`), `'B'` for the second (`-`), `'C'` for the third (`6`).

Here's a simple way to do this, involving some typing and the obligatory copy-and-paste errors:

```ml
header_row_entry(Header, Row, Entry) :-
    Header = num('', ColumnName, _, _),
    Row = num(RowName, Value, _, _),
    Entry = num(RowName, ColumnName, Value).
header_row_entry(Header, Row, Entry) :-
    Header = num('', _, ColumnName, _),
    Row = num(RowName, _, Value, _),
    Entry = num(RowName, ColumnName, Value).
header_row_entry(Header, Row, Entry) :-
    Header = num('', _, _, ColumnName),
    Row = num(RowName, _, _, Value),
    Entry = num(RowName, ColumnName, Value).
```

This enumerates all the entries in a row on backtracking:

```ml
?- Header = num('', 'A', 'B', 'C'), Row = num('B', 8, -, 6),
      header_row_entry(Header, Row, Entry).
Header = num('', 'A', 'B', 'C'),
Row = num('B', 8, -, 6),
Entry = num('B', 'A', 8) ;
Header = num('', 'A', 'B', 'C'),
Row = num('B', 8, -, 6),
Entry = num('B', 'B', -) ;
Header = num('', 'A', 'B', 'C'),
Row = num('B', 8, -, 6),
Entry = num('B', 'C', 6).
```

To enumerate all the entries in an entire table, it remains to enumerate all rows, then enumerate row entries as above. Here this is:

```ml
table_entry(Entries, Entry) :-
    Entries = [Header | Rows],
    member(Row, Rows),
    header_row_entry(Header, Row, Entry).
```

And now, given your table:

```ml
?- Table = [num('', 'A', 'B', 'C'), num('A', -, 4, 5), num('B', 8, -, 6), num('C', 2, 3, -)], table_entry(Table, Entry).
Table = [num('', 'A', 'B', 'C'), num('A', -, 4, 5), num('B', 8, -, 6), num('C', 2, 3, -)],
Entry = num('A', 'A', -) ;
Table = [num('', 'A', 'B', 'C'), num('A', -, 4, 5), num('B', 8, -, 6), num('C', 2, 3, -)],
Entry = num('A', 'B', 4) ;
Table = [num('', 'A', 'B', 'C'), num('A', -, 4, 5), num('B', 8, -, 6), num('C', 2, 3, -)],
Entry = num('A', 'C', 5) ;
Table = [num('', 'A', 'B', 'C'), num('A', -, 4, 5), num('B', 8, -, 6), num('C', 2, 3, -)],
Entry = num('B', 'A', 8) ;
Table = [num('', 'A', 'B', 'C'), num('A', -, 4, 5), num('B', 8, -, 6), num('C', 2, 3, -)],
Entry = num('B', 'B', -) .  % etc.
```

Depending on what you want exactly, it remains to lowercase the row and column names (the irritatingly named `downcase_atom` in SWI-Prolog, for example) and filter out the `-` entries. You can then assert the entries using a failure-driven loop or by collecting all of them using `findall` and asserting using `maplist`.

Now that we have a working solution, we might want `header_row_entry` to be a bit nicer. We can use `arg/3` to capture more explicitly that we are trying to pair a column name and a value that are at the same argument position in their respective header and row terms:

```ml
header_row_entry(Header, Row, Entry) :-
    arg(1, Row, RowName),
    functor(Header, _, Arity),
    between(2, Arity, ArgIndex),
    arg(ArgIndex, Header, ColumnName),
    arg(ArgIndex, Row,    Value),
    Entry = num(RowName, ColumnName, Value).
```

This is shorter than the above and applicable to any number of columns in the table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @IsabelleNewbie. As told by you, I can use maplist to make entries as facts. I have added the the work performed by me above. Can you please explain, how and where I should use maplist to make facts (Neglect the filtering of - and lowercase for now). So, that when I query ?-num(A,B,X). I should get the output.